# Keras: IoU backend implementation where the inputs are the box corners?

Tags: keras, coordinates, backend, metrics

I've seen a few implementations of Intersection over Union in Keras Tensorflow, but they all use inputs that represent the contents of the box regions. The network I'm working with passes the four corners of the boxes themselves. How can I implement the algorithm this way with Keras backend?

My attempt:

```
 def IoU():
        # y_true: Tensor from the generator of shape (B, N, 5). The last value for each box is the state of the anchor (ignore, negative, positive).
        # y_pred: Tensor from the network of shape (B, N, 4).
        # box coordinates (in axis 2): [x1, y1, x2, y2]
     def _IoU(y_true, y_pred):
          anchor_state = y_true[:,:,-1]
          regression = y_pred
          regression_target = y_true[:,:,:-1]
          indices = backend.where(keras.backend.equal(anchor_state, 1))
          regression = backend.gather_nd(regression, indices)
          regression_target = backend.gather_nd(regression_target, indices)
          x1_pred = regression[:,0] # <- fails here 
          y1_pred = regression[:,1]
          x2_pred = regression[:,2]
          y2_pred = regression[:,3]
          x1_true = regression_target[:,0]
          y1_true = regression_target[:,1]
          x2_true = regression_target[:,2]
          y2_true = regression_target[:,3]
          xA = keras.backend.maximum(x1_pred, keras.backend.transpose(x1_true))
          yA = keras.backend.maximum(y1_pred, keras.backend.transpose(y1_true))
          xB = keras.backend.maximum(x2_pred, keras.backend.transpose(x2_true))
          yB = keras.backend.maximum(y2_pred, keras.backend.transpose(y2_true))
          interArea = keras.backend.maximum((xB-xA+1),0)*keras.backend.maximum((yB-yA+1),0)
          pred_area = (x2_pred-x1_pred+1)*(y2_pred-y1_pred+1)
          truth_area = (x2_true-x1_true+1)*(y2_true-y1_true+1)
          iou_arr = interArea/(pred_area + keras.backend.transpose(truth_area) - interArea)
          iou = keras.backend.mean(iou_arr)
          return iou
      return _IoU
```

After some debugging I found that backend.gather_nd reduced regression and regression_target from shapes (?, ?, 4) to shapes (?, 4), hence the indexing for x1_pred.

However, when I try to use this as a metric for a compiled model, I get the following error during runtime:

```
 ValueError: slice index 2 of dimension 1 out of bounds. for 'metrics/_IoU_1/strided_slice_4' (op: 'StridedSlice') with input shapes: [?,2], [2], [2], [2] and with computed input tensors: input[1] = <0 2>, input[2] = <0 3>, input[3] = <1 1>.
```

If anybody knows a way that I can implement this in Keras, or sees where I've gone wrong, I'd be forever grateful.

EDIT: I figured out that this was because the method was being called twice, once where (y_true, y_pred) were the box prediction/truth (and the last dimension was of shape 4), and then again where (y_true, y_pred) were the class prediction/truth (and I have only 2 classes).

I did get some negative values and some values > 1 for the returned iou values, so maybe I'm still doing something incorrectly?